# How can i find the equation of a line passing 2 points and point passing by line -python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, jupyter-notebook

i have two points:

```
(283,240,302)
(150,150, 50)
```

I want to know equation of the two point , and i want to find (x,y,z)
distance R from point(150,150,50)

[image]

Comment: can you show me sorce code?

Comment: my programming ability is not good...

Comment: your problem is not clear what are those blue curves representing ? The description hints you want linear interpolation/extrapolation `p(t) = p0 + (p1-p0) *t` `p0,p1` are your points and the scalar parameter `t` depends on what point you want. if `p1-p0` is unit vector than `t` is signed distance from `p0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using vectors : compute `AB` vector, and the use proportionality to compute `AC` vector. Then compute C position from `AC`:

```
A = (150, 150, 50)
B = (283, 240, 302)

from math import sqrt

AB = [A[i] - B[i] for i in range(3)]
length_AB = sqrt(sum([u*u for u in AB]))
AC = [u*600/length_AB for u in AB]

C = [AC[i]+A[i] for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: ----> 7 length_AB = sqrt(sum([u for u in AB]))